# REST API + Expand Recurring Calendar Events?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, wcf, odata

Is there a way using the REST API (through javascript) to expand recurring calendar items?  Or is there a helpful client side utility to assist with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the REST API with Javascript will not give you the recurring calendar items.
If you want to retrieve the recurring calendar items with client side code, you need to take a look at SPServices: http://spservices.codeplex.com/

Take a look at this thread:
http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/254560

Answer (score 1):

Look into the RecurrenceData field: `[site]/_api/Web/Lists(guid'[[GUID]')/Items([ID])/RecurrenceData`.
You get an string of xml. You can transform it to JSON if needed. 
The object you get back is different depending on the type recurrence (daily, weekly, monthly, yearly), so you'll have to add some logic to accomplish what you need.

Comment: is it possible?

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to fetch the calendar items using REST Api and expand the recurring events using SPEventsParser library([GitHub repository](https://github.com/JoeHogan/sharepoint-events-parser)).

first Get the calendar items using REST like this:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Calendar')/items?$select=*,Duration,RecurrenceData
```

then call the library function to expand the recurring event like this:

```
var parsedArray = spEventsParser.parseEvent(eventObject);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example for this?

Comment: Sure, i'll post an example soon

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, this is what worked for me using Graph API to access a SharePoint calendar list in azure and get RecurrenceData:

```
/v1.0/sites/root/lists/<list_guid>/items?$expand=fields($select=Title,RecurrenceData)
```